# Configured SessionFactory: null

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have created basic hibernate application. It throw error message.

**Error is:**

```
     Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.5
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : com/crmcall/entity/CallUsers.hbm.xml
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: com.crmcall.entity.CallUsers -> crmcallusers
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : com/crmcall/entity/Customers.hbm.xml
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: com.crmcall.entity.Customers -> crmcustomermaster
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : com/crmcall/entity/User.hbm.xml
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: com.crmcall.entity.User -> crmusers
Oct 18, 2012 3:36:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: component class not found: string
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.crmcall.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:27)
        at com.crmcall.dao.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:23)
        at com.crmcall.dao.UserDAO.main(UserDAO.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component class not found: string
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.buildType(Component.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1102)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1287)
        at com.crmcall.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: string
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:101)
```

This is my Hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
     <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/crmtest</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
   <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <mapping resource="com/crmcall/entity/CallUsers.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/crmcall/entity/Customers.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/crmcall/entity/User.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my User.hbm.xml

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.crmcall.entity.User" table="crmusers">
      <composite-id name="userPK" >
           <key-property name="businessUnit" column="BusinessUnit" type="string"/>
           <key-property name="userID" column="UserID" type="string"/>
      </composite-id>

        <property name="recID" >
          <column name="RecID"/>
        </property>

        <property name="password">
          <column name="Password"/>
        </property>

        <property name="userName">
          <column name="UserName"/>
        </property>

        <property name="userType">
          <column name="UserType"/>
        </property>

        <property name="userLevel">
          <column name="UserLevel"/>
        </property>

        <property name="customerCode">
          <column name="CustomerCode"/>
        </property>

        <property name="customerCodeson">
          <column name="CustomerCodeson"/>
        </property>

        <property name="locationCode">
          <column name="LocationCode"/>
        </property>

        <property name="lastUpdatedBy">
          <column name="LastUpdatedBy"/>
        </property>

        <property name="lastUpdatedOn" type="timestamp">
          <column name="LastUpdatedOn"/>
        </property>

      <property name="email" type="string">
          <column name="Email"/>
        </property>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is my calling place :

```
     public class UserDAO {
    private Session session = null;

    public UserDAO() {
        session =  HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    }

     public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        Transaction tn = session.beginTransaction();
        List<User> users = session.createQuery("from crmusers cu order by cu.UserID").list();
        System.out.println("==" + users.size());
        tn.commit();
        return users;
    }


     public static void main(String[] args){
         UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
         userDAO.getAllUsers();
     }
}
```

This is my project folder structre:
[image]

Please tell me what is an issue in my code?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

In User.hbm.xml you have to use `type="java.lang.String"` (with a big 'S'). That's it.

Answer (score 1):

AS I understand the problem in your code was caused by your *User.hbm.xml* mapping file. To be more precised by *type="string"* attribute of *composite-id* tab.

As I understand you don't need to put type attribute obligatory so try to skip it at all; hibernate should detect it automatically. I'm not sure in last sentece because I have not used composite keys, but there are a lot of examples where peoples don't define type explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, in your mapping file you have

```
<key-property name="businessUnit" column="BusinessUnit" type="string"/>
<key-property name="userID" column="UserID" type="string"/>
```

That should be `...type="java.lang.String"...` instead, but most likely you really don't need it - Hibernate will make a (usually very good) educated guess.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate use the `reflection` to determine the mapping type at `runtime`.
It seems your mapping is correct, But if you still getting the same problem.
I will **suggest** you to remove the `type attribute` for the time being test, from all the `String` type properties such as email,businessUnit,userId

try this way for all the `String` type properties

```
       <property name="email">
          <column name="Email"/>
        </property>
```

or you can try with `java.lang.String` also

```
       <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
          <column name="Email"/>
        </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both "string" and "java.lang.String" are aliases for org.hibernate.type.StringType, so either should work in terms of naming types.

I am actually not so sure the problem is in the mapping for User.  That mapping looks fine.  Based on that exception I would more expect that somewhere you have

```
<composite-id ... class="string">
```

or

```
<component ... class="string">
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<composite-id name="userPK" >
       <key-property name="businessUnit" column="BusinessUnit" type="String"/>
       <key-property name="userID" column="UserID" type="String"/>
  </composite-id>
```

try with changing string to String